# How to get list of folders in sidebar?

Tags: finder, applescript

How to get the list of folders in the sidebar using AppleScript?

It is okay to get the list of all items too since I will be able to search for them

Comment: If you just want a list of names of the items in the Sidebar, then it's very easy to get a list of the items in the Sidebar in Finder using UI Scripting and System Events, however it varies a bit based on the OS version. What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Finder's Sidebar is a location for shortcuts to be easily accessible by the user.

From Apple's [Human Interface Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/sidebars/):

> the sidebar in a Finder window includes a list of frequently accessed locations and tag-based search shortcuts. The user can select one to access its contents or results in the main portion of the window.

Additionally, having a folder list is not practical in this element. Anything more than 2 levels of hierarchy (which is highly plausible in a folder listing) is discouraged.  In this instance, Apple states that a [column view](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/windows-and-views/column-views/) be used.

> **In general, refrain from exposing more than two levels of hierarchy within a sidebar**. In some cases, a second sidebar may be warranted
>   when a data hierarchy is deeper than two levels. If your app requires
>   the navigation of deeply nested objects, consider implementing a
>   column view.

Bottom line; Apple discourages 3rd party developers from doing this, meaning Apple's Finder is definitely not going to show files like this.

**You can put a shortcut *to* a folder, but you won't get a *list* of folders.**

Comment: thank you for your answer, what I want to do is get the folders list and compare them to a premade list, because finder wipe them out sometimes when the machine is restarted, I want to compare them if they don't exist I add them, that's the reason, you might have a work around this, thank you

Comment: That's an entirely different question from this one meaning it needs to be a new question (if applicable - it hasn't been asked and answered already).  What you want to do is *compare* a list of files/folders with a known list and this can be done in AppleScript or in Bash (Terminal).  Personally, I prefer Terminal.

Comment: but as you mention before it seems not very possible to get the list of items on the sidebar in first place...

Comment: Just because it can't be in the side bar doesn't mean it can't be in a window.  If you do this in programmatically, why not just have the script tell you what's changed?  Why write a script that you have to manually search?

Comment: Yes I would like to, I just could not find how